# Raspberry pi picture capture every 5 seconds

Tags: linux, image, camera, save, raspberry-pi

I have multiple webcams hooked up to my raspberry pi and they are compatible and work. I want the raspberry to take a picture every 5 seconds (with every camera), save it to /var/www/picture.jpeg (picture2.jpeg and picture3.jpeg) and repeat overwriting the old images. Im not quite sure how to achieve this and need help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may use `guvcview` or `motion`, I forgot with which argument you need to run, but just lauch it with `--help` and you will get all the information. Actually, I've never tried with more than onw camera, but I think that it is possible to do it. You may have to search. But for the delay, there is no problem with those to programs.